# JavaFX setting Button style on Mouse Click

Tags: java, css, button, javafx, mouseevent

I've got a problem with a Java project I'm working on: I'm creating a grid of buttons via code in javafx on a pane. The buttons are all types of a subclass of the javafx Button class that i wrote.

Here's the header of the class:

```
private final String BASIC_STYLE = "-fx-font: 6 arial;";
private final String CLICKED_STYLE = "-fx-background-color: #0f0";

private int row;
private int col;
private String category;
private boolean selected = false;
```

Within the constructor i do the follwing:

```
this.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            toggleSelected();
        }
    });
```

Here's the toggleSelected() Method:

```
public void toggleSelected() {
    this.selected = !selected;
    this.setStyle(selected ? this.BASIC_STYLE : this.BASIC_STYLE+this.CLICKED_STYLE);   
}
```

It's basically supposed to swap the style everytime you click the button. When i click the button, the button first gets selected by the OS (the border is becoming blue) and only after i click a second time on the exact same button it'll become green (the style that i'm giving it via setStyle).
However, the selected property becomes true on the first click and false on the second click, which means i click once on the button and it gets a blue border and selected = true, if i click on it a second time it becomes green and selected = false and if i click on it a third time it becomes normal again but selected will be true again. 
I find it to be really strange that the first click on a button changes the "selected" variable correctly but not the style. Why is this happening and how can i avoid that i've to select the button first before i can click it?

Comment: What's the style initialized to?

Comment: In the constructor:   this.setStyle(this.BASIC_STYLE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize

```
selected = false ;
```

and

```
setStyle(BASIC_STYLE);
```

But your event handler enforces the rule

```
selected == true -> setStyle(BASIC_STYLE);
selected == false -> setStyle(CLICKED_STYLE);
```

So your initial state is inconsistent with the state your handler enforces.

From the initial state, the first time you click, `selected` is set to `true` which causes `setStyle(BASIC_STYLE)` (which is the value it already has, so nothing changes). From then on, everything will switch as required.

You either need to change the initial state, or switch the logic of the `setStyle(...)` call in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ButtonEnterAction extends Button {

    boolean selected = true;

    public ButtonEnterAction(String connect) {
        setText(connect);
        action();
    }

    public ButtonEnterAction() {
        action();
    }

    private void action() {
        EventHandler<KeyEvent> enterEvent = (KeyEvent event) -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                fire();
            }
        };
        addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, enterEvent);

//        setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
//            @Override
//            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
//                SepiaTone st = new SepiaTone();
//                setEffect(st);
//            }
//        });
//        setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
//            @Override
//            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
//                setEffect(null);
//            }
//        });
    }

    @Override
    public void fire() {
        super.fire(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        if (selected) {
            SepiaTone st = new SepiaTone();
            setEffect(st);
        } else {
            setEffect(null);
        }
        selected = !selected;
    }

}
```

Create the Instant Class in ButtonEnterAction is like.

```
ButtonEnterAction bea = new ButtonEnterAction("TestButton");

        bea.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("hello");
            }
        });
```